# How to build release vscode version

Tags: visual-studio-code

---

this question is for open source vscode(which is under MIT license), not VS Code. I spent yesterday trying to find out how to build some kind of release version. By that I mean, like in Visual Studio we have "Debug" and "Release" build. I am C# developer, and vscode is all based on web technology, to say it like that. Did some javascript in college, history now. I don't know where to start. Can anyone point me in the right direction and what to learn? For starters, just how to produce working folder with customized exe?

---

**What I did find out**: I see that it runs with electron, started it in debug mode following instructions "Build and Run From Source" on GitHub, but it is debug, I read that I need to put it in electron "app" folder or pack, tried, but without luck, don't know which files. Total lack of knowledge. I couldn't find any tutorial like this question, or just couldn't see it in sea of other "how to do build something with vscode" but not vscode itself. Thank you, I hope I was clear and sorry for long text and lousy English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of days of reading and learning I did find the answer. For windows build there is gulp task, type in console while in project directory "gulp vscode-win32", find ready to use build outside of vscode directory named "VSCode-win32", other build tasks are in "gulpfile.vscode.js". For learning, read about gulp, electron, Node.js, and how they work together, and file structure, from there you can understand how they work together and how to customize.

Comment: This is essentially a "read the manual" answer, which isn't very helpful :(