# What are the steps to package and release VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron

I am trying to figure out how to package an unchanged fork of VS Code.

My first steps were to follow the [electron application distubution documentation](https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/application-distribution/), which has not been successful. I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36886228/how-to-build-release-vscode-version), where another user had the same question. However, the `vscode-win32` gulp task seems to have been replaced by `x64` and `ia32` versions, and when I try running these tasks they generate an `out-vscode` folder as opposed to a full electron project.

This led me to believe that I can use this new out folder (as well as node modules, packages.json, etc.) with the [electron release](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/tag/v1.6.6) being used by VS Code to mimic the `resources/app` folder from the installed version of VS Code in Program Files, however when I try running `electron.exe` using this method I get:

> The factory method of "vs/code/electron-main/main" has thrown an exception TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined

In short, I have been struggling with this for a couple of days, and I am out of ideas. If anyone has packaged the project and can offer a suggestion for how to do so, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The issue seemed to be due to being branched off of `master` as opposed to `release`. I'd assume there are changes in `main` that aren't accounted for in the gulp task.

For anyone confused by my post, the expected behavior for a successful build is for a folder named `VSCode-win32-x64` to be generated in the directory where your vscode clone is located.